# Is it possible to add a callback to FormsAuthenticationTicket expiration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The FormsAuthenticationTicket works as expected. I'm setting it to "now + 60 seconds" and after it expired, my next action redirects me to the login-page.
Though I have to reset a license as soon as the ticket expires. Is there any way to achieve this? I can't find any event handler to attach such functionality.
I'm also open for different approaches.
My goal is to logout the user after a specific time interval and call a method to free the license.

Comment: You'd possibly need a custom module to inspect each incoming request and detect if a possibly expired cookie is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest implementation I can think of is use global.asa.cs or global.asa.vb depending on your language. You might need to store a separate cookie from the ticket with the unique license identifier so when the **session_end** method is call, you can grab the cookie and from the browser and revoke the license from that session. If you didn't use a cookie, could stored a database table active userid & license key, and each time **session_end** is call, you could see if the user is still logged in and if not, revoke the license.

See Methods:

**Session_Start:** Fired when a new user visits the application Website.The Session_Start event is fired the first time when a user’s session is started. This typically contains for session initialization logic code.

**Session_End:** Fired when a user's session times out, ends, or they leave the application web site.